# Get Signature for Tuple input for EIP712

Tags: web3js, contract-development, struct, ecdsa, eip712

I'm using web3.js to try and sign a tuple and get the signature. I'm utilizing `draft-EIP712Upgradeable.sol` in order to hash and recover the input in solidity. I originally looked at the following link for guidance, but the solution provided did not work.
[Signing a tuple (struct) for ECDSA.recover](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118928/signing-a-tuple-struct-for-ecdsa-recover/129556#129556)

The code I have in Solidity is as Follows:

```
struct ticket {
        address to;
        uint256[]  amounts;
        bytes32[]  merkleProof;
        bytes  signature;
    }

function verifySigner(ticket calldata _ticket) internal view returns (address) {
        bytes32 digest = _hash(_ticket);
        return ECDSA.recover(digest, _ticket.signature);
    }

    function _hash(ticket calldata _ticket) internal view returns (bytes32) {
        return _hashTypedDataV4(keccak256(abi.encode(
            keccak256("ticket(address to,uint256[] amounts,bytes32[] merkleProof)"),
            _ticket.to,
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_ticket.amounts)),
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_ticket.merkleProof))
```

On the java side, I built with React in Js and Web3.js. The code for me attempting to obtain the signature is as follows:

```
Ticket = {
        "to": accounts[0], //Account sending the transaction
        "amounts": amounts, // Array of values. I used [1,1,1]
        "merkleProof": hexProof //Array containing the hex proof using created merkle tree and leaf node for account sending transaction.
    };

 const structHash = web3.utils.soliditySha3(
            {type: "address", value: Ticket.to},
            {type: "uint256[]", value: Ticket.amounts},
            {type: "bytes32[]", value: Ticket.merkleProof}
        );

let signature = await web3.eth.sign(structHash, accounts[0])
```

No matter what I've tried, I can't seem to successfully recover the address of the account that sent the transaction. Do I need to incorporate the Domain separator into the hash before signing? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been stuck on this for almost a week now.

### **Update**

The Domain in the solidity contract is set to:

```
string private constant SIGNING_DOMAIN = "NFTSig";
string private constant SIGNATURE_VERSION = "1";
```

On the Java side I don't have it being utilized which I realized but wasn't able to determine how to use it correctly. 
For testing my assumption was that the struct hash in Solidty prior to using the `_hashTypedDataV4()` function should match what I get in my js script. i.e.

```
keccak256(abi.encode(
            keccak256("ticket(address to,uint256[] amounts,bytes32[] merkleProof)"),
            _ticket.to,
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_ticket.amounts)),
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_ticket.merkleProof)
```

should match the hash I get in js, but I'm not so sure that is true.

Comment: Can you share your domain on both sides?

Comment: @FatihFurkan I've updated the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay so it took me many hours to figure this out but I finally got it. After reading some EIP712 resources this worked:
No changes were made on the Solidity side. However, on the Java side, I made a typed data JSON with my input struct and signing domain as follows

```
//Layout Struct types

    const domain = [
        { name: "name", type: "string" },
        { name: "version", type: "string" },
        { name: "chainId", type: "uint256" },
        { name: "verifyingContract", type: "address" }
    ]

    const typeTicket = [
        { name: "to", type: "address" },
        { name: "amounts", type: "uint256[]" },
        { name: "merkleProof", type: "bytes32[]" },
    ]

    //Create data structs

    const domainData = {
        name: "NFTSig",
        version: "1",
        chainId: await web3.eth.getChainId(),//Come back and hardcode the ID later
        verifyingContract: await nftInstance.options.address
    };

    const Ticket = {
        "to": signer,
        "amounts": amounts,
        "merkleProof": hexProof
    };

//Put them together in one data structure

    data = {
        types: {
            EIP712Domain: domain,
            Ticket: typeTicket,
        },
        primaryType: "Ticket",
        domain: domainData,
        message: Ticket
    };
```

Once I had that setup, to get the signature, I used the eth-sig-util to get the signature:

```
prvtKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

const sig = ethSigUtil.signTypedData_v4(Buffer.from(prvtKey, 'hex'), {data});
```

Here are some of the resources I used in figuring it out:
https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712#definition-of-hashstruct
https://github.com/MetaMask/eth-sig-util/blob/v4.0.1/src/sign-typed-data.ts#L49
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58257459/solidity-web3js-eip712-signing-uint256-works-signing-uint256-does-not](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/signing-data.html#signing-data-with-metamask)
https://magic.link/docs/advanced/blockchains/ethereum/javascript
https://morioh.com/p/d3ef8b16c770

Comment: What do you do with the signature? Are you basically just using it to verify the sender on chain?